# Delete columns from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 4 columns that are repeated in all the tables in the database and I have to delete them

[image]

How can I do this deletion without having to enter table by table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server provides [system information schema views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) that can be queried to retrieve information about the database.

In your case, the [`COLUMNS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) view can be used to fetch the names of all tables containing a specific column name.

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN (
    'ID_Integracion_CodBodega',
    'ID_Integracion_FechaUltRep',
    'ID_Integracion_ControlTrigger',
    'ID_Integracion_CodBodega_Origen'
);
```

From there, you can use the normal process to [delete a column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/delete-columns-from-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15) from an existing table.

```sql
ALTER TABLE [table_name] DROP COLUMN [column_name];
```

---

You should be **very** careful with this approach. It is easy to drop a column you didn't mean to.

Be aware of any constraints/dependencies in your database schema that you might be affecting with this action.

- Are there [constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-table-constraint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on your tables that will be affected by the removal of these columns? (Especially `ON DELETE CASCADE` constraints that may impact other tables).
- Are there views/stored procedures/triggers that depend on these columns?
- Do you have queries/dynamic SQL that will be impacted by the removal of these columns?

Answer (score 2):

**This code will output the necessary SQL to make the changes.**

`STRING_AGG` is used twice to group up the columns and tables. `QUOTENAME` is used to place brackets around names correctly.

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(
N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.object_id) + N'
    ' + c.ColumnSql, N'
')
FROM sys.tables t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT ColumnSql = STRING_AGG(CAST(N'DROP COLUMN ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) AS nvarchar(max), N'
    ')
    FROM sys.columns c
    WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id
      AND c.name IN (
        'ID_Integracion_CodBodega',
        'ID_Integracion_FechaUltRep',
        'ID_Integracion_ControlTrigger',
        'ID_Integracion_CodBodega_Origen'
    )
) c
```

You can execute it all together by using

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG.....
);

EXEC(@sql);
```

I caution you against using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` because it is only there for compatibility.